# Magento: Get a reference to search results within catalog/layer/view.phtml

Tags: php, magento

I need to access the currently loaded search results as an array but from within `catalog/layer/view.phtml`.

I've tried using the following code, but it returns an empty array...

```
$products = $this->getLayout()  
                 ->getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_list')
                 ->getLoadedProductCollection()
                 ->toArray();

echo "<pre>".print_r($products,true)."</pre>";
die();
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Just can confirm, that your code works for me. I tested it on Magento CE 1.6.2.0 What is your version of Magento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the search Model.

Here is the code to get the Search model:

```
$search = Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/advanced');
```

Here is the code to search your products:

```
$search = Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/advanced')->addFilters(array('name' => $term));
```

Then to get the results in an object, enter the following line:

```
$search->getProductCollection();
```

Good luck,

Pesach

Comment: Strangely, this doesn't work for me either. I still get an empty array!